# Magento after login SSL, page redirects to https account dashboard

Tags: ssl, https

We have Magento and we have secure login page. After you login it directs you to account page and the url is https and every page after that is https. How can we make the page after login or page after any https page go to http. It is causing issues with a module.

We just want the login and the checkout to be https. If a person is at https checkout and wants to go back to an unsecure part of the store, we would like the url to go back to http.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason the problem module needs http?

If not, fully secure is better, not least because Google likes it. I would do a find across your problem module for hard-coded http: references and change them to https

Comment: Im not sure why the module doesnt function properly in https and i see your point on doing storewide https for google purposes, but right now i want to quick fix this and only have login and checkout https while rest of the store is http. right now when leaving an https page the next page whatever it is will automatically get https. I will quick fix this and then purchase the module and get the support for it to have them make it work with storewide https. Right now the module i have came with a template from template monster and the module maker will not support it.

Comment: I don't think you are going to find a quicker fix by bouncing in and out of https. Do you use an IDE? In phpStorm, for example, I can do a find for any string in any scope - file, folder, or the whole project. If you have command line access to the server you could do the same thing with  grep : http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html